# heroku deploy issue with angularjs 7

Tags: heroku

The deployment of angularjs 7 app in heroku showing error like application error.

[image]
error info

Comment: Can you check the logs in Heroku and add them to your question. Without them, your question cannot be answered. Click the "check your logs for details" link or using the command line type `heroku logs --tail` as is shown in the error message.

Comment: !    You do not have access to the app .